# Need to animate Text And Button in Row using MotionLayout in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-animation, android-motionlayout

I have a row and inside that I have a **Text** and a **Button**
Initially only Text Will be visible but as soon as animation starts the button will come from the
right to left and text will wrap around and will come to multiple lines
Here is the below code I have tried
What mistake I am making here any help would be appriciated here stuck here from quite some time
You can copy paste and run the whole code just make sure to add this dependency
   `implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout-compose:1.1.0-alpha13")`

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MyApplicationTheme {
                TestCompose()
            }

        }
    }


    @Composable
    fun TestCompose() {
        val context = LocalContext.current
        val scene = MotionScene() {
            val text = createRefFor("text_block")
            val button = createRefFor("button_block")
            val row = createRefFor("row")

            val start1 = constraintSet {

                constrain(text) {
                    top.linkTo(parent.top, 15.dp)
                    start.linkTo(parent.start, 15.dp)
                    width = Dimension.wrapContent
                    height = Dimension.wrapContent
                    visibility = Visibility.Visible
                }
                constrain(row) {
                    width = Dimension.fillToConstraints
                    height = Dimension.wrapContent
                }

                constrain(button) {
                    visibility = Visibility.Gone
                    width = Dimension.value(40.dp)
                    height = Dimension.value(20.dp)
                }
            }

            val end1 = constraintSet {
                constrain(text) {

                    top.linkTo(parent.top, 15.dp)
                    start.linkTo(parent.start, 15.dp)
                    width = Dimension.wrapContent
                    height = Dimension.wrapContent
                    customColor("background", Color.Red)
                }
                constrain(button) {
                    visibility = Visibility.Visible
                    top.linkTo(text.top, 20.dp)
                    start.linkTo(text.end, -100.dp)
                    end.linkTo(parent.end, 200.dp)
                    width = Dimension.value(20.dp)
                    height = Dimension.value(20.dp)
                    translationX = -400.dp
                }

                constrain(row) {
                    width = Dimension.wrapContent
                    height = Dimension.wrapContent
                }
            }
            transition(
                from = start1,
                to = end1,
                name = "default",
            ) {

            }
        }

        val progress = remember {
            Animatable(0f)
        }

        val animatetoEnd by remember {
            mutableStateOf(true)
        }

        MotionLayout(
            motionScene = scene,
            progress = progress.value,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
        ) {

            LaunchedEffect(key1 = animatetoEnd) {
                progress.animateTo(
                    if(animatetoEnd) 1f else 0f,
                    animationSpec = tween(5000)
                )
            }
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(10.dp)
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .layoutId("row")
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = "You have selected our best seller seats(s))",
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .layoutId("text_block")
                        .fillMaxWidth(),
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.W500
                )
                Button(
                    onClick = {},
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .background(Color.Red)
                        .layoutId("button_block")
                ) {
                    Text(text = "Click Here")
                }
            }
        }


    }
```

The Output that I am getting here
[image]

The desired output
[image]